# How to remove emoji in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a dataframe below and I wanna remove the emoji

```
col1    col2
-------------
Hi  ｜  14

hey ｜  8
-------------
```

I have tried using the code below to remove emoji

However, the error message shows `remove_emoji() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

I would like to know if there's anything wrong to my code and if there's other way please let me know.
Thank u very much.

```
def remove_emoji():
    for text in df["col1"]:
        return emoji.replace_emoji(text, replace="")

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(remove_emoji)
```

Comment: What is it about the error message that confuses you? You wrote a function that takes zero arguments (and presumably operates on some global `df` variable we can't see), but used it in a context (a Pandas `apply` call) that expects one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's more clear, `df['col1'].apply(remove_emoji)` is equivalent to
`df['col1'].apply(lambda x: remove_emoji(x))` so your function should have a parameter `x` and I'm assuming you don't need that `for` loop because your function will be applied on each item of your series (`df['col1']`) individually.
So your function should just be :

```
def remove_emoji(text):
    return emoji.replace_emoji(text, replace="")
```